# PushPlugin not found for iOS PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I just installed PhoneGap 3.5 and the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) using the PhoneGap CLI.  I created a project using the PhoneGap CLI.  In the `receivedEvent` method of index.js, I added these lines:

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.register(myTokenMethod, onError, {"badge": "true", "sound": "true", "alert":"true", "ecb": "mycallback"}
```

this leads to the error in xCode of:

```
CDVPlugin class PushPlugin (pluginName: PushPlugin) does not exist
ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found or is not a CDVPlugin.  Check your plugin mapping in config.xml
```

And although the instructions do not indicate I need to for automatic installation of the plugin, I went ahead and added

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
  <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

to my config.xml and receive the same error.  The plugin version is 2.4, I am using an iPhone 6 as a test device and xCode 6.

Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your PushPlugin.m inside `Build Phases > Compile Sources`

[image]

Comment: this did resolve the issue, but I wound up trashing the project, creating a brand new project, and copying over my html files.  Re-installed everything and it just worked.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add the .m file with the + icon and it worked like a charm on the next build.